# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los valores de una lista que se encuentra dentro de otra lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista que contiene más listas dentro de ella y estas tienen 3 valores.
Por ejemplo:

> List = [['Gerardo', 4.5, False], ['Maria', 10, True], ['Roberto', 9.6, True]]

¿Hay alguna manera para acceder a los valores que se encuentren dentro de alguna de estas listas?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por ayudarme! Me fue de mucha ayuda, espero ya con esto resuelto, poder terminar mi proyecto. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Las listas de listas se tratan con una matriz esto quiere decir que si quiero acceder al valor 'Maria' lo hago así `list[1][0]`.

Nota que no utilizo `List` sino `list`, porque `List` es una palabra reservada del lenguaje Python y te dará problema si la utilizas como una variable

Comment: Corrección. `list` es la palabra especial en python y no `List`. De todas formas ninguno de los dos es palabra reservada. Una palabra reservada no puede usarse como identificador, pues si lo haces python se niega a compilar el programa. No es el caso de `list`, que no daría error, pero no conviene usarlo como identificador para no confundir y para no perder su significado original.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo bien te dice Jimy Hendrix Falcón Cárdenas en su respuesta una lista de listas se trata cómo una matriz. Cuando tu tienes esto

```
lista = [['Gerardo', 4.5, False], ['Maria', 10, True], ['Roberto', 9.6, True]]
```

Te lo puedes imaginar así

```
lista = [['Gerardo', 4.5, False],
         ['Maria', 10, True],
         ['Roberto', 9.6, True]]
```

Por lo tanto lo tratas cómo si tiene 3 filas y 3 columnas, es decir, 2 dimensiones y por lo tanto para poder acceder a todos los valores necesitaras dos corchetes, `lista[][]`.

Queremos ver la nota de Roberto, fila 2 (recuerda que siempre empezamos a contar desde 0), columna 1. Dicho con código, `lista[2][1]`.

Queremos ver nombre de María, fila 1, columna 0. `lista[1][0]`

Si lo que queremos es **toda** la info de María, fila 1. `lista[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Aunque otras respuestas de han dado la solución, que consiste en usar dos índices así: `List[i][j]`, la explicación que dan no es del todo correcta.

La sintaxis con dos corchetes `[i][j]` no es un caso especial porque lo que tienes sea un arreglo o array. De hecho, no lo es ya que un arreglo o array es un tipo de datos organizado por filas y columnas en el que *todos los elementos son del mismo tipo*, lo cual no es necesariamente cierto en python, y de hecho no lo es en tu caso.

Lo que tienes no es más que una lista, cuyos elementos en lugar de números son otras listas. Así, si tu lista es:

```
List = [['Gerardo', 4.5, False], ['Maria', 10, True], ['Roberto', 9.6, True]]
```

es una lista con **tres** elementos (como podrías comprobar si haces `len(List)`). Por tanto es perfectamente válido acceder a `List[0]`, `List[1]` o `List[2]`.

Ahora bien, cada uno de esos elementos es *otra lista* (como puedes comprobar si imprimes `type(List[0])`, que te mostrará `list`). Como tal lista, puedes *volver a aplicar* un índice a ella para acceder a sus elementos, y así `List[0][0]` seleccionaría en primer lugar al primer elemento dentro de `List`, que es otra lista, y en segundo lugar al primer elemento dentro de esa otra lista.

Por tanto la sintaxis `List[i][j]` no tiene nada de especial. Es una mera consecuencia de que los elementos de `List` sean a su vez listas.

**PS:** El nombre `List` para una variable no es muy apropiado. En primer lugar comienza por mayúscula, y según la convención habitual los nombres que comienzan por mayúscula deberían usarse para nombres de clases, y no de variables. En segundo lugar se parece demasiado a la palabra `list` que es un tipo de datos en Python. Llamarla así puede inducir a confusión aunque el lenguaje te lo permita. Si llamas `list` a una variable, dejaría de funcionar correctamente la función `list()`, por ejemplo, que sirve para convertir a lista su argumento.